# Как вывести в тег число от 0 до 340?

Tags: javascript, svg

Сделал спидометр и прикрепил для  интерактивности range в диапазоне от -90 до 90 который регулирует угол поворота стрелки ...

Так же есть некий информер то есть цифра которая выводит скорость - она пока статичная

Я хочу что бы в зависимости от положения range выводилась цифра но не могу понять как это реализовать

Если к примеру присвоить цифре значение range то получится - 90 чего не может быть

Вот мой пример

```js
range.addEventListener("input", function() {
  document.querySelector(".figure").style.transform = `rotate(${this.value}deg)`;
});
```

```css
.figure {
  transform-origin: 0 -20px;
  transition: 0.34s ease;
}

.data text {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-250 -250 500 250" width="280">
  <g class="figure" transform="rotate(-90)">
    <circle r="20" cy="-20" />
    <path d="M-20,-20 0,-150 20,-20" />
  </g>

  <g class="scale">
    <circle r="200" cx="0" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="10 50" />
    <circle r="210" cx="0" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke="green" />
    <circle r="210" cx="0" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke="red" stroke-dasharray="220 600" stroke-dashoffset="-300" />
    <circle r="210" cx="0" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke="yellow" stroke-dasharray="220 600" stroke-dashoffset="-80" />
  </g>

  <g class="data">
    <path d="m-220 0 a120 -120 0 0 1 440 0" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="0" id="path" />
    <text dx="25">
      <textPath href="#path">40</textPath>
    </text>
    <text dx="95">
      <textPath href="#path">60</textPath>
    </text>
    <text dx="155">
      <textPath href="#path">80</textPath>
    </text>
    <text dx="210">
      <textPath href="#path">120</textPath>
    </text>
    <text dx="280">
      <textPath href="#path">200</textPath>
    </text>
    <text dx="345">
      <textPath href="#path">220</textPath>
    </text>
    <text dx="420">
      <textPath href="#path">260</textPath>
    </text>
    <text dx="480">
      <textPath href="#path">280</textPath>
    </text>
    <text dx="550">
      <textPath href="#path">300</textPath>
    </text>
    <text dx="610">
      <textPath href="#path">320</textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
  
 <text id="num" text-anchor="middle" aligment-baseline="central" y="-100" style="font-size: 50px; font-family: sans-serif;">0</text>
</svg>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<input type="range" min="-90" max="90" value="-60" id="range">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формула для пересчёта

```
speed = speedmin + (speedmax - speedmin) * (range - rangemin) / (rangemax - rangemin)
```

Для `-90..90 => 0..340`

```
speed = 340 * (range + 90) / 180
```

Вообще казалось бы, что базовое значение - всё таки скорость, а угол поворота стрелки спидометра из неё считается.

Comment: О, этот волшебный JS ;)  `Number(this.value)`. Округление только надо сделать

Comment: yes //  thank you so much